# Make Mac Parallels IIS website accessible from Internet

Tags: mac, iis, hosts, parallels

I am developing an e-commerce site that is nearly finished, last thing I need to do is debug an issue with a callback from the payment gateway.

I am running Windows through Parallels Mac and want to get the callback to hit IIS.

I have been trying to get this sorted for a few days now, can anyone help please?